# Most App Execution Aliases do not open from the Run Dialog

Tags: windows, windows-11, run-dialog

I have Windows 11 version 22H2 (0S Build 22621.2361). When opening the "Run Dialog"and typing the name of a App Execution Alias, the app does not open and for a split second `WERFault.exe` opens up and shows in the Task Manager.

This problem started a month ago and I can't remember what changed from the time that It worked until now.

**Here is a list of the execution aliases that do not work**

- `mspaint`
- `notepad`
- `wt`
- `SnippingTool`

**And here is a list of some that work:**

- `winget`
- `pbrush`
- `wsl`
- `MediaPlayer`.

All of them work just fine opened from Command Prompt or Windows Powershell.

There is 1 bug report for this exact problem [here](https://aka.ms/AAdcwhz), posted about 1 year ago, and another thread [here](https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/cant-open-notepad-or-mspaint-from-run-command-win-r.298142/) again talking about this issue with no solution to be found.

Interestingly, when instead of running `mspaint`, I run `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\mspaint`. It works. I thought that maybe the Run Dialog opens a different mspaint.exe by searching somewhere else that the system `%PATH%`, but I checked the Windows Error Reporting archive and that does not seem to be the case as the app is indeed opened.

Here is a [link](https://pastebin.com/Ejtfm4JK) to the document generated by WERFault.exe:

I am completely out of Ideas on what could cause such behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After suffering for months with this problem, I finally investigated and found a solution. After searching the Windows registry, I found the following key:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
```

In my case, all the keys inside it were outdated and simply deleting them made shortcuts like `mspaint` and `notepad` work again